# start specific iis 6.0 website via script

Tags: iis, iis-6

I've googled around and can't find a clear answer.

I simply want to start some of my iis 6.0 websites via a script that will be run on start up.

anyone got any tips for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've googled around, and [this is what I've found](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/22971/iis-scripting-solutions.html).
Snippet :

```
cd \inetpub\adminscripts    
Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs START_SERVER W3SVC/1
```